# How to Rewrite Path?

Tags: nginx

How do I write path from http://127.0.0.1:8888/storage/app/media/ to http://127.0.0.1:8888/v/ ?

And leave any filename and extensions after it.

I've tried:

```
location /v {
    rewrite ^/v /storage/app/media/ last;
}


location /v {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/storage/app/media/;
}


location /v {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    rewrite ^/v /storage/app/media/ last;
}


location ~ ^/v/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/storage/app/media(.*) /v/$1 last;
}


location ~ ^/v/(.*) {
    return 301 /storage/app/media/$1;
}
```

Going to http://127.0.0.1:8888/v/file.mp4 shows Page Not Found.

http://127.0.0.1:8888/storage/app/media/file.mp4 still displays url without rewrite.

**Edit:**

I was able to mask the path with

```
rewrite ^/v/(.*)$ /storage/app/media/$1 last;
```

How do I now redirect /storage/app/media to alway go to /v/?

I've tried:

```
location ~ ^/storage/app/media(.*) {
    return 301 /v/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want:

1. clients accessing `/storage/app/media/xxx` to be redirected to `/v/xxx`, and
2. `/v` to map to physical files under `/path/to/storage/app/media`.

You can use a `rewrite...last` to map `/v` to `/storage/app/media` (as you have discovered) but it means that your server must accept both URIs, which make implementing (1) without a loop possible but tricky.

An alternative would be to use `alias` instead:

```
location /v {
    alias /path/to/storage/app/media;
}

location /storage/app/media {
    rewrite ^/storage/app/media(.*)$ /v$1 permanent;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried with the rewrite and then the alias. Visiting /storage/app/media/file.mp4 doesn't redirect to /v/file.mp4. Using alias without rewrite makes /v/ 404 error.

Comment: There may be conflicting location blocks or statements in your configuration. It may help if you edit the question and add the entire `server` block.